# standard protocol on inserting data and querying data at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

every day we have an SSIS package running to import data into a database.

sometimes people are querying the database at the same time.

the loading (data import) times out because there's a table lock on the specific table.

**what is the standard protocol on inserting data and querying data at the same time?**

Comment: It all depends on the data and business rules.  There is no standard protocol.  That said taking a table lock is pretty extreme.  They should have a good reason.   I only take table locks when I suspect (or expect) that would be the only process updating the table during that time period.   A page lock is a better mix of performance without shutting down the whole table.

Comment: @Blam are you saying that the SSIS process doesnt necessarily take the table lock?

Comment: Sorry the way I read it was a table lock by something other than the package.  So the table lock is coming from the package?   If so I will delete my comment.

Comment: yes i believe so but i dont know. it could be coming from a query. but nowhere do we explicitly say that the table is locked

Comment: If SSIS is timing out because there is a lock you would assume the lock was already there.  Unless the SSIS package is locking itself out by taking multiple locks on the same table.  I could not think of many cases where you would want SSIS (or any import) to take multiple locks on the same table.

Comment: Can you schedule the import for the off-hours? We try not to do any imports during our main business hours.

Comment: @HLGEM definitely can; however, there's someone querying the database all the time

Answer (score 2):

There are several strategies.

One approach is to design your ETL pipeline as to minimize lock time. All the data is prepared in staging tables and then, when complete, is switched in using fast partition switch operations, see [Transferring Data Efficiently by Using Partition Switching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). This way the ETL blocks reads onyl for a very short duration. It also has the advantage that the reads see all the ETL data at once, not intermediate stages. The drawback is difficult implementation.

Another approach is to enable snapshot isolation and/or read committed snapshot in the database, see [Row Versioning-based Isolation Levels in the Database Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177404%28v=sql.105%29). This way reads no longer block behind the locks held by the ETL. the drawback is resource consumption, the hardware must be able to drive the additional load of row versioning.

Yet another approach is to move the data querying to a read-only standby server, eg. using [log shipping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895393%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

First you need to figure out where those locks are coming from.   Use the link to see if there are any locks.

[How to: Determine Which Queries Are Holding Locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677357%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

If you have another process that holds a table lock then not much you can do.

Are you sure the error is "not able to OBTAIN a table lock".   If so look at changing your SSIS package to not use table locks.